# HTML submit form and onclick event from the same button

Tags: html, forms, onclick

I'd like to submit a form and go back to where the user came from using a button in HTML. My button looks like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="history.back(-1)" />
```

The form gets submitted but the onclick doesn't redirect. Is there an easy way to do this or do I need to create a JS function or do something server-side?

Comment: you should send data by ajax and  do history.back(-1).

Comment: you can use `<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="window.location.href=history.back(-1)"/>`

Answer (score 0):

You should handle your form submission with Ajax, and to prevent browser default behavior do like this:

```html
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="handleSubmit()" />
```

```js
function handleSubmit(e) {

    //prevent default behavior of browser on submit form
    e.preventDefault();
    
    //do your job here
    sendDataToExampleAPI();

    //back to previous address in browser
    window.history.back();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Majid! I tried this now:

    function handleSubmit(e) {

        //prevent default behavior of browser on submit form
        e.preventDefault();

        //do your job here
        var form = document.getElementById("form-id");
        form.submit();

        //back to previous address in browser
        window.history.back();
    }

The form submits but the browser still doesn't go back. There's an error in the browser but it flashes so quick that I can't read it...

Comment: @Muriel set handleSubmit function for form onsubmit event and try again

Comment: Error is something about "e" being undefined.

Answer (score 0):

`history.back()` method alone in HTML does not do anything.

You should have a function in JS that calls `history.back()` and pass that function to your `onclick` in HTML. Plus, `history.back()` method does not receive any arguments. It automatically goes 1 step back. Alternatively, you can use `history.go(-1)`.

So, something like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="goBack()" />
```

```
function goBack() {
  history.back();
}
```

[Check this for reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/back)

Also, to submit the form, your `<input>` should be inside `<form>` tag, like this:

```
<form id="form">
  <input type="submit">Submit form/>
</form>
```

Comment: So if I do this:
```
<input type="button" value="gobackonly" onclick="history.back(-1)" />
```

it goes back (but doesn't submit the form)

Comment: Your input type should be "submit" to submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

`history.back(-1)` you should use `window.location.href=history.back(-1)` instead

```
<input type="submit" onclick="window.location.href=history.back(-1)"/>
```

You should use it.

Also, don't forget to use `e.preventDefault()`to prevent unexpected behavior in form submission.

You may also need to submit data with Ajax.

Comment: Thanks Gucal, I tried this but the browser stays with the form - form does submit though...

Comment: Can you try without using -1. `window.location.href=history.back()` or `window.history.back()`

Comment: If it doesn't submit a form like that, you should call the `window.history.back()` function inside the form submit function.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it in the am and let you know how it goes. Really appreciate the help :)

Comment: I hope it will be successful. Good luck :)